# Input value jQuery check length and value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm still stuck here when validating the value of the input. If the value is between `0.4` and `0.9` the input `n2` will remove the read-only. On another hand where if value less than `0.4` or more than `0.9` it will show up modal dialog. My question here is to validate the value/length if the value key in by the user is not in decimal value? let say user insert value 1, then my jquery
won't firing out because my length is `>=3`.. if I put the length check `> 1`, then when user key the decimal value for example `0.5`, the modal dialog
will pop out 3 times..  since my length value is `>= 3`.. if I remove the length checking, it will keep pop out the modal dialog whenever user key in value length that more than one.
My question is how to control such a situation if the valid range value is between `0.4` to `0.9`, at the same time can checking value that not in decimal number as well? Is it possible?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm da" name="da" id="da" value="" autocomplete="off" />

<div class="form-group actionDiv" style="display:none">
<label for="cdaaction">Action </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm cdaaction" name="cdaaction" id="cdaaction" value="" />
</div>

<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm n2" name="n2" id="n2" value="" autocomplete="off" readonly />

$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".da").keyup(function() {
            var dInput = $(this).val();

            if ($('.da').val().length >= 3) 
            {
                if(dInput < 0.4 || dInput > 0.9)
                {
                    var mymodal = $('#mi-modal');
                    mymodal.find('.modal-body').html('Is the value correct: '+ $('.da').val() +'  ?');
                    mymodal.find('.modal-footer').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="modal-btn-si">Yes</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-btn-no">No</button>');
                    $("#mi-modal").modal('show');

                    $("#modal-btn-si").on("click", function(){
                    $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
                    $('.actionDiv').show();
                    });

                    $("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function(){
                    $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
                    $('.actionDiv').hide();
                    $("#da").focus();
                    });
                    $(".n2").attr('readonly', true);

                }
                else
                {
                    $(".n2").removeAttr("readonly");
                    $('.actionDiv').hide();
                }
            }


            });
        });
```

Comment: Do you inspect `dInput` to be a number? if so why not use `type="number"` on the input with the id `da`

Comment: actualy i got function that i not included here where that input only can key in numbering  `function isNumberKey(evt)
  {
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
   if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
   return false;

   return true;
  }` onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" at the input

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes it allowed numbering only. the.i have own purpose to do so. actually at 1st attempt fill the input user might able to key in value within the range or not within range.. not wihin range means the value will be store as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseFloat()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".da").keyup(function() {
        //var dInput = $(this).val();

        var val = parseFloat($(this).val());


            if (!isNaN(val) && (val < 0.4 || val > 0.9))
            //if(dInput < 0.4 || dInput > 0.9)
            {
                var mymodal = $('#mi-modal');
                mymodal.find('.modal-body').html('Is the value correct: '+ $('.da').val() +'  ?');
                mymodal.find('.modal-footer').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="modal-btn-si">Yes</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-btn-no">No</button>');
                $("#mi-modal").modal('show');

                $("#modal-btn-si").on("click", function(){
                $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
                $('.actionDiv').show();
                });

                $("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function(){
                $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
                $('.actionDiv').hide();
                $("#da").focus();
                });
                $(".n2").attr('readonly', true);

            }
            else
            {
                $(".n2").removeAttr("readonly");
                $('.actionDiv').hide();
            }
        }


        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider triggering your code on `blur()`. When the user focusses out of the input box, you can check whether the inputted value is correct or not.

Furthermore, what Carsten said is true: Use `type=number` for your input and you won't need the check on the input length, just on the value.

Comment: the input have validation. 1st attempt if user input the value not within then range it will be able to be edited at the 2nd attempt where they able to edit. the purposse i disable the input so that the old input is remain there and the new input will be appear in the modal dialog and there user will key in the correct value in the modal dialog.